# Disable Tenant Scoped SPFx solution for a subset of Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I have a tenant scoped SPFx solution which is applied across all sites in SharePoint Online.

It deploys a megamenu and some branding.

I would like to disable/uninstall the solution for a few sites, but since the solution is tenant scoped I cannot simply uninstall on those sites.

Please can you help with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the powershell command `Get-PnpCustomAction -Scope All` to check the solutions.

Then use command `Remove-PnPCustomAction -Identity <ID of the solution> -Scope web` to remove the custom action from current web.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpcustomaction?view=sharepoint-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpcustomaction?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: I looked at this, but it only works for Site and Web Scoped solutions. If the solution is tenant scoped, it will not be returned and cannot be removed using this method. Try deploying a tenant scoped solution and then connect to a specific site and use GetPnPCustomAction -Scope All. It will not be returned.